# javascript how to change function from imperative to functional

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

i am new in functional programing, and developing web app using angularjs. I am try to change some formal function to functional. functional method has one entry and only one return, and should no side effect inside function. but in my function i change the status in for loop, so i guess i have to separate below to several block?
imperative return true/false and change status in one circle of for loop
what i expected is that change to functional and no additional for loop

```
function checkStatusOfChildTest(childList) {

            for (var i = 0; i <childList.length;i++) {
                var keys = Object.keys(childList[i]);
                if (keys.length === 1 && keys[0] === '$status') {
                    if (childList[i][keys[0]] === 'create') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        //just mark the status of child as delete, then remove child when save finally
                        childList[i][keys[0]] = 'delete';
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            //if no status is new one
            return true;

        }
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0). By adding "= 'delete'" you code has an unwanted side effect. That part should be moved to somewhere else.

Comment: yes i see, i tried to move childList[i][keys[0]] = 'delete'; to another function where i have to iterate array again to set the status to 'delete', how can i avoid shch extra cost, imperative approach only need one for loop but functional need two

Comment: _functional method has one entry_ - no, because curried/uncurried functions have a one-to-one correspondence, i.e. you can transform one into the other and vice versa (aka isomorphism). Look into `curry`/`uncurry` combinators.

Comment: _and only one return_ - technically yes, but you can always use a composite type (e.g. tuples) and thus return several values. Besides there is continuation passing style, an encoding where a function returns nothing but calls another functions and thus can pass several arguments.

Comment: Please note that angular is meant and optimized for imperative code. You won't get happy and won't benefit much if you start mixing up angular with functional style.

Comment: Are you effectively just trying to filter `childList`?